# saving available balance in shared prefernce

Tags: java, android

i'm making money calculation app where evrything is working fine except that whenever i calculate money from available balance and close the app and reopen the app available balance is resetting to default value that is 2000 and not the calculated amount for this purpose i'm using shared preference but it doesnt seem to be saving the value
my code for calcuation on button click with shared preference

```
  //calculation part

                int total = (train_ticket_amount == null || train_ticket_amount.equals("") ? 0:Integer.parseInt(train_ticket_amount))
                        + (bus_ticket_amount == null || bus_ticket_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bus_ticket_amount))
                        + (bike_amount == null || bike_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bike_amount))
                        + (share_rickshaw_amount == null || share_rickshaw_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(share_rickshaw_amount));
                result = Integer.parseInt(textavailablebalance2) - total;
                textAvailableBalance1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
                 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                result = settings.getInt("price",0);
                final_amount = textAvailableBalance1.getText().toString();
                //end of calculation part
```

i'm using shared preference on onPause Method as well

```
 protected void onPause() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("price", result);
        editor.apply();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

and in oncreate too so i'm not getting where i'm going wrong with this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work);
        initializeContent();
        setSpinner();
        inputExpenseGiven.setEnabled(false);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView2.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView3.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        result = settings.getInt("price",0);
    }
```

//Entire code on button click with onPause and onResume

```
        public void submit_btn(final View view) {
        arrival = inputfrom.getText().toString();
        destination = inputTo.getText().toString();
        travel_type = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        workdescription = inputdescription.getText().toString();
        expense_given = checkBoxExpense.getText().toString();
        expense_amount = inputExpenseGiven.getText().toString();
        train_pass = checkBoxpass.getText().toString();
        train_ticket = checkBoxTrain.getText().toString();
        train_ticket_amount = inputamount1.getText().toString();
        bus_ticket = checkBoxBus.getText().toString();
        bus_ticket_amount = inputamount2.getText().toString();
        bike = checkBoxBike.getText().toString();
        bike_amount = inputamount3.getText().toString();
        share_rickshaw = checkBoxShareRickShaw.getText().toString();
        share_rickshaw_amount = inputamount4.getText().toString();
        textavailablebalance2 = textAvailableBalance1.getText().toString();

        //calculation part

// Save the calculated result price instead of picking the old one

        int total = (train_ticket_amount == null || train_ticket_amount.equals("") ? 0:Integer.parseInt(train_ticket_amount))
                + (bus_ticket_amount == null || bus_ticket_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bus_ticket_amount))
                + (bike_amount == null || bike_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bike_amount))
                + (share_rickshaw_amount == null || share_rickshaw_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(share_rickshaw_amount));
        result = Integer.parseInt(textavailablebalance2) - total;


        if(!expense_amount.isEmpty())
            result+=Integer.parseInt(expense_amount);
        textAvailableBalance1.setText(Integer.toString(result));

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("price", result);
        editor.apply();


        //second calculation
        amountused = (train_ticket_amount == null || train_ticket_amount.equals("") ? 0:Integer.parseInt(train_ticket_amount))+
                (bus_ticket_amount == null || bus_ticket_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bus_ticket_amount))+
                (bike_amount == null || bike_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bike_amount))+
                (share_rickshaw_amount == null || share_rickshaw_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(share_rickshaw_amount));
        textfinalamount.setText(Integer.toString(amountused));
        amountused1 = textfinalamount.getText().toString();
```

//xml

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAvailableBalance1"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="2000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_submit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textAvailableBalance" />
```

Comment: Debug your code and find out the culprit .

Comment: get value from SP in onResume instead of onCreate

Comment: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/writing-and-reading-from-sharedpreferences/

Comment: Hello @Niranj Patel sir i added shared preference in onResume still not working as i have also added shared preference on button click because calculation is happening on button click so is it ok

Comment: so it's working on button click?

Comment: it is calculating amount on button click but not saving in shared preference i also add shared preference onResume method

Comment: it's should work without saving in OnClick. may be your variable again assign any value. one more thing try to use commit instead of apply for editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the code in your **onPause() method**

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("price", result);
        editor.apply();
```

And also from **onResume() method**,

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        result = settings.getInt("price",0)
```

It is enough **storing result when the calculation is done**.

And If you want to display the latest result in the textview,

In **onCreate()** add this line

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 result = settings.getInt("price",2000);//default result 2000
 textAvailableBalance1.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

The problem is, You are not setting the text which is stored in SharedPref to your textview

**Edit**:

You can use this code,

```
         int total = (train_ticket_amount == null || train_ticket_amount.equals("") ? 0:Integer.parseInt(train_ticket_amount))
                + (bus_ticket_amount == null || bus_ticket_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bus_ticket_amount))
                + (bike_amount == null || bike_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bike_amount))
                + (share_rickshaw_amount == null || share_rickshaw_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(share_rickshaw_amount));
        result = Integer.parseInt(textavailablebalance2) - total;


        if(!expense_amount.isEmpty())                
           result+=Integer.parseInt(expense_amount));
        textAvailableBalance1.setText(Integer.toString(result)); 

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("price", result);
        editor.apply();


        //second calculation
        amountused = (train_ticket_amount == null || train_ticket_amount.equals("") ? 0:Integer.parseInt(train_ticket_amount))+
                    (bus_ticket_amount == null || bus_ticket_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bus_ticket_amount))+
                    (bike_amount == null || bike_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bike_amount))+
                    (share_rickshaw_amount == null || share_rickshaw_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(share_rickshaw_amount));
        textfinalamount.setText(Integer.toString(amountused));
        amountused1 = textfinalamount.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Hello Jyoti JK ma'm it is working now so i dont understand why it was not working previously when should i use onPause and resume

Comment: I will work, But it is unwanted. The problem is, You are not setting the text which is stored in SharedPref to your textview.

Comment: nice job Jyoti JK Mam :)

Comment: @Smith .. that's what I suggested . You forgot to store the values after calculation . 

 textAvailableBalance1.setText(String.valueOf(result));

You missd that part . Still great solution worked

Comment: sir i have one more question that if expense is given for someday it should be added to available balance i tried doing this if(inputExpenseGiven.getText()!= null){ expense_amount1 = Integer.parseInt(textavailablebalance2) + (expense_amount == null || expense_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(expense_amount)); textAvailableBalance1.setText(Integer.toString(expense_amount1)); } but it is returning negative amount

Comment: @Smith check !expense_amount.isEmpty in if

Comment: i think i messed up entire calculation because onstart of activity it is showing 0 available and onClick of button it is printing just expense amount i again updated my question

Comment: and on calculation it is giving negative value

Comment: i messed up entire calculation --> You are right. just try long and dont use int if the value is bigger. And get the text from textview if it is not empty. And use it for calculation

Comment: try `extAvailableBalance1.setText(result+Integer.toString(expense_amount1));`

Comment: but mam i wanted to add expense_amount with available balance text and do not want to create another textview because expense will be given one or two day not always so any solution and still it showing value in negative and onStart  of activity 0 avaialble balance

Comment: i reinstalled app but still it is starting with 0 and showing negative amount

Comment: It shows negative amount  because textavailablebalance2 may be less that total

Comment: but when i uninstall and reinstall textAvailableBalance1 starts with 0 which i have set to 2000 initial amount

Comment: It is better to set text 2000 in xml also.

Comment: i have settext in my xml as 2000

Comment: after unstalling and reinstalling apk i think it should show available balance with 2000 but it is starting with 0

Comment: May be your sharedpref is not  deleted after uninstall. Please post question if you have diff problems than commenting

Comment: hii i found the solution it was shared preference default value in oncreate was set to 0 i changed it to 2000 thanks

Answer (score 0):

//calculation part

// Save the calculated result price instead of picking the old one

```
            int total = (train_ticket_amount == null || train_ticket_amount.equals("") ? 0:Integer.parseInt(train_ticket_amount))
                    + (bus_ticket_amount == null || bus_ticket_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bus_ticket_amount))
                    + (bike_amount == null || bike_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(bike_amount))
                    + (share_rickshaw_amount == null || share_rickshaw_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(share_rickshaw_amount));
            result = Integer.parseInt(textavailablebalance2) - total;
            textAvailableBalance1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("price", result);
            editor.apply();
             //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            //result = settings.getInt("price",0);
            final_amount = textAvailableBalance1.getText().toString();
            //end of calculation part
```

Comment: Shekawat sir i updated my question with buttonclick code

Comment: Can you debug  your code  and specifically  and set breakpoint while saving values and check values 

And check what editor.putInt("price", result);
        editor.apply();
returns while debugging

Comment: Ravindra sir it is working now thank you for all your patience and time thank you very much

Comment: What I suggested was the solution .You forgot to set it on textview but great if issue got resolved .

Comment: sir i have one more question that if expense is given for someday it should be added to available balance i tried doing this 
        if(inputExpenseGiven.getText()!= null){
       expense_amount1  =  Integer.parseInt(textavailablebalance2) +
               (expense_amount == null || expense_amount.equals("")? 0:Integer.parseInt(expense_amount));
       textAvailableBalance1.setText(Integer.toString(expense_amount1));
        } but it is returning negative amount

Answer (score 0):

every time you save value in `SharedPreference`, you have to put this

`editor.commit();`

after

`editor.putInt("price", result);`

Comment: what is difference between commit and apply?

Comment: commit() writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply() will handle it in the background

Comment: niranj sir i was using commit but android studio suggested of using apply instead

Comment: and sir what are the other things which should remember while using shared preference